# Can Flute of the Outer Gods be used for monsters "not on the board" like in The Terrible Experiment?

Tags: arkham-horror

The [Flute of the Outer Gods](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Flute_of_the_Outer_Gods) says the following (emphasis mine):

> **Any Phase:** Lose 3 Sanity and 3 Stamina and discard Flute of the Outer Gods before making a Combat check to defeat all monsters **in your current area**. This does not affect Ancient Ones.

Another answer on this site [about the Flute](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/3549/3389) states that it can be used at either a location or a street. However, there are other locations that monsters can be, such as the Outskirts and The Sky, but you can't attack those so it's moot about whether you can be used there.

But what about monsters that are in a location where you *can* attack them, but are not "on the board"? For instance, there is [The Terrible Experiment](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/The_Terrible_Experiment) rumor that says the following (emphasis mine):

> When this card enters play, place 5 monsters from the cup on it. Any player may choose to fight one or more of these monsters while in the Miskatonic U. streets during the Arkham Encounter Phase. If defeated, they are claimed as monster trophies. These monsters do not move, **are not considered on the board**, and do not count against the monster limit.

Are they in "your current area" despite not being on the board? Can you attack one of these monsters, pass a Horror check, then instead of a Combat check use the Flute of the Outer Gods to destroy all of the monsters? This came up in our last game and we weren't sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**,

While I'd be tempted to allow this as it would be a very cool thing to do and it is hard to find a good use for the Flute of the Outer Gods, this question is addressed directly in the [FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/FAQs/Complete_Arkham_FAQ.pdf), pg 10.

> **Q:** Do cards that affect monsters at Miskatonic University
>   (such as the “Campus Security Increased” Mythos card or
>   the “Flute of the Outer Gods” Unique Item) affect monsters
>   spawned by “The Terrible Experiment”?
>
> **A:** No. Those monsters are not actually on the board; they
>   can only be fought as if they were.